# Flutter - trouble making navigation bottom menu

Tags: android, flutter, dart

PLEASE HELP ME - I have error in context navigation push script in my flutter project

Code :

```
FloatingActionButton(
  child: Icon(Icons.add),
  onPressed: () {
    Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => FormTambahData(
                  paramData: null,
                  regid: 0,
                )));
  },
),
```

Comment: Can share the error message here

Comment: I see that in my VSCode debug console there is no error, but when I run the code Navigation.push(context there is a red underscore in context.

The instance member 'context' can't be accessed in an initializer.
Try Replacing the reference to the instance member with a different expressiondart

Comment: oh sorry, after I refreshed, there was an error in the debug console.

: Error: Undefined name 'context'.
lib/dashboard.dart:152
            context,
            ^^^^^^^

Comment: Ok. Share the code sample here

Comment: what if I share an external link? because I can never post the full code on stackoverflow I don't know why either

Comment: this is the full source code https://pastebin.com/Vy7VcZh1

Comment: check this link https://gist.github.com/rashmisridar/4071d557583d23e85c7636e6f69d9c41

Comment: ok i will see your github

Comment: there is no error, but why is the add button on the profile tap, right?

I want to add a circle button that serves to direct to the add data page on the dashboard tap in the bottom menu

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241452/discussion-between-rashmi-bhandari-and-crico).

Answer (score 1):

go to your `item` method and add `BuildContext` like this:

```
class _DashboardState extends State<Dashboard> {
//  _items = [
  List<Widget> item(BuildContext context) {...}
```